# redirect with htaccess from /0/1/my_image_0_1.jpg to my_image_0_1.jpg

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm working my way to have urls like this:

`my_domain.com/images/0/1/my_image_0_1.jpg` to this: `my_domain.com/images/my_image_0_1.jpg`

You see? I'm trying to avoid showing the folders named `0` and `1`.

I have the following rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule /images/(.*)_(.*)_(.*).jpg$ html/images/$2/$3/$1.jpg
```

This works like a charm. The thing is that my image needs to be named: `my_image.jpg` and as you can see in my example I named my image `my_image_0_1.jpg` to "encode" the folder the image is actually in.

Let's make another example: `images/my_image_2_3.jpg` will be inside the folders `images/2/3` or the complete path: `images/2/3/my_image_2_3.jpg`. Hope that's clear enough.

Well, I believe that's all that needs to be explained,.
I want to show `images/my_image_0_1.jpg` but to be redirected to the real path: `images/0/1/my_image_0_1.jpg`. I want to **maintain** the names on my images (if possible). Is there any way to achieve this using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?images/([^/]+?_([^_]+)_([^._]+)\.jpg)$ html/images/$2/$3/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: @anubhave Remember that if possible I want to maintain the current name of the images which is `my_image_0_1.jpg` and with your rule I'm redirecting to `my_image.jpg`. Hope that's clear and thank you for answering that fast.

Comment: **Rewrite** yeah, you're right about that! And nope, that's not what I want. What I want is from `images/my_image_0_1.jpg` to `images/0/1/my_image_0_1.jpg`. You're wrong just in the name of the file. Hope I made myself clear. :P